# Reuse object/property in different stages of a declerative pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

We create a new maven build:

```
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
```

Now we want to reuse this rtMaven in a different stage than the current one;
like in the code below:

```
pipeline {
agent any

...
stages {

    stage('stage1') {
        steps {
            script {
                def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
            }
    }

    stage('stage2') {
         steps {
            script {
                //REUSE rtMaven (now it's unknown)
            }
         }

     }
}
```

Is it possible to reuse the rtMaven without redefining it again in the second stage?

Now we have an error like:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: rtMaven for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the var in global scope

```
def rtMaven = ''
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('stage1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
                }
            }
        }
    stage('stage2') {
        steps {
            script {
                echo "$rtMaven"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a clean way to define´ `def rtMaven = ' '` above your pipeline?

Comment: @lvthillo yes, unless you have a node block. In such cases one can restrict the variable to node block and reuse them in multiple stages in the same node block.